# Docker MACVLAN Ports not mapping correctly

Tags: node.js, docker

I'm running a Docker container with the MACVLAN network driver so the container has an IP address on my network. The container is running a NodeJS app on port 3001. I use the following command to run the Docker container:

`docker run --net=vlan1 --ip=172.16.3.14 -p 172.16.3.14:80:3001 --name iptv-staging -t iptv-staging`

The container starts up without issue and is accessible at 172.16.3.14, however only when I browse using :3001. It is not accessible via port 80 as mapped. `docker container ls` does not show ports for that container:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                  COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                        NAMES
2aa1273ad7cd        iptv-staging           "node app.js"            10 minutes ago      Up 10 minutes                                    iptv-staging
```

Inspecting the Docker file seems to show the correct port mapping:

```
"PortBindings": {
            "3001/tcp": [
                {
                    "HostIp": "172.16.3.14",
                    "HostPort": "80"
                }
            ]
        },
```

I've also tried launching without the HostIP defined:

`docker run --net=vlan1 --ip=172.16.3.14 -p 80:3001 --name iptv-staging -t iptv-staging`

But with the same result. Not sure where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Any luck with this one? I am facing a very similar issue.

Comment: does anyone have any updates on this issue?

Comment: Hi, I re-read the Docker documentation, it seems that using MacVlan driver isn't possible map any ports. This is because the IP of the container is assigned to "parent" interface directly. This means that Docker does not use any kind of virtual bridge for the running container. All ports are directly available. If you need to map a port you need to use or iptable in the host, or iptable inside containers.